# Sort a multidimensional array by two variables

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks something like below, but it could potentially contain more drafts.

```
$multi_arr = array(
    'draft1' => array (
        'alloc_coeff' => 560,
        'steps_count' => 2,
        'order_draft' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'whse_id' => 4,
                'quantity' => 0,
                'percent' => 0
            ),
            '1' => array(
                'whse_id' => 1,
                'quantity' => 10,
                'percent' => 66.666666666667
            )           
        )
    ),
    'draft2' => array (
        'alloc_coeff' => 1517,
        'steps_count' => 1,
        'order_draft' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'whse_id' => 1,
                'quantity' => 10,
                'percent' => 66.666666666667
            )      
        )
    ),
    'draft3' => array (
        'alloc_coeff' => 559,
        'steps_count' => 2,
        'order_draft' => array(
            '0' => array(
                'whse_id' => 2,
                'quantity' => 0,
                'percent' => 0
            ),
            '1' => array(
                'whse_id' => 1,
                'quantity' => 10,
                'percent' => 66.666666666667
            )           
        )
    )
);
```

I need to sort the content by using two variables: `alloc_coeff` and `steps_count`.

First `alloc_coeff` needs to be considered from the highest to the lowest value.

And then as a second variable the `steps_count` from lowest value to highest.

```
usort($multi_arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['alloc_coeff'] <=> $b['alloc_coeff'];
});
```

I don't need the entire array to be rewritten and stored in a temporary variable, I just need the keys sorted like this (expected outcome) `draft2`, `draft1` and lastly `draft3`.

What's a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
array_multisort(array_column($multi_arr, 'alloc_coeff'), SORT_DESC,
                array_column($multi_arr, 'steps_count'), SORT_ASC,
                $multi_arr);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/924894 And https://eval.in/924892

Note:- tested in 5.6.23 and PHP 7.0.8

Comment: Wow! That is so simple! Thanks.

Comment: @Borsn   glad to help you :):)